# rails redirect user to profile page after destroy action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form for work_histories.  When a user deletes a work history I would like them to be redirected to their users profile page instead of the user_work_histories_url which calls this controller action (work_histories#show).  I wanted to redirect to the users profile page which is user_path(@user).

I tried changing the work_histories destroy action to redirect to user_path(@user) instead of user_work_histories_url but it says the id of the job I just deleted couldn't be found.

here's my controller for work_histories

```
# DELETE /users/:user_id/work_histories/:id
def destroy
@work_history = WorkHistory.find(params[:id])

@work_history.destroy
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to user_work_histories_url, 
                notice: "The work history for your #{@work_history.job_title.upcase} job was successfully destroyed." }
  format.json { head :no_content }
end
end
```

here's the show.html.erb for work_histories

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Job Title:</strong>
  <%= @work_history.job_title %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Job Description:</strong>
  <%= @work_history.description %>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Back', user_work_histories_path(@user) %> |
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_work_history_path(@user, @work_history) %> | 
<%= link_to 'Delete', user_work_history_path(@user, @work_history), method: :delete, 
    data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this work history?' } %>
```

Comment: Are you keeping the notice message when you change the url? Maybe you should create the notice message before you delete the record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I figured it out.  I'm not sure if this is the "rails way" of doing it or if it's just another one of my hacked together solutions though.

I was in the work_history controller trying to call user_url(@user) which is how i do it in the users controller but looks like it works when I change it user_url(@work_history.user).  work history belongs to user.  It works...for now.

```
# DELETE /users/:user_id/work_histories/:id
def destroy
@work_history = WorkHistory.find(params[:id])

@work_history.destroy
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to user_url(@work_history.user), 
                notice: "The work history for your #{@work_history.job_title.upcase} job was successfully destroyed." }
  format.json { head :no_content }
end
```

end